# A locally injective but non globally injective function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

A continuous function $f : U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, is said to be *locally injective* at $x_0 \in U$ if exist a neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $x_0$ s.t. $f|_V$ is injective. $f$ is said to be *locally injective on $U$* if is locally injective at all points of $U$.

If $n=1$, clearly $f$ is locally injective on $U$ iff it's injective on $U$. If $n >1$, this is false (at least is what I believe).

Does anybody know a counterexample i.e. a continuous function which is locally injective on an open $U$ set but it's not injective on $U$?

[**observation**] if $f$ is locally injective, by the invariance domain theorem is a local homeomorphism. if $f$ is also proper (i.e. the counter-image of a compact set is compact), then it's also a global homeomorphism (Caccioppoli theorem), and consequently injective. This means the counterexample cannot be a proper map.

[**edit**] I forgot to specify that I was interested in **continuous** functions.

Comment: A condition on the function might be missing. Otherwise, in dimension 1, the function "fractional part" is locally injective but not injective on R.

Comment: Look at $z \mapsto z^2$ on $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus \{0\}$, for example.

Comment: @Didier Piau: you are right, I was thinking about continuos functions.

Comment: What is $U$? ${}$

Comment: "If $n=1$, clearly $f$ is locally injective on $U$ iff it's injective on $U$." What about $U = (0,1) \cup (1,2)$ and $f|_{(0,1)} = \mathrm{id}$, $f|_{(1,2)}= \mathrm{id} - 1$?

Comment: $U$ was supposed to be open, but as your example shows, the interesting question arises when $U$ is connected.

Comment: A covering map, and in general every local homeomorphism, is a counter-example!

Comment: @AngeloLucia could you elaborate more on Caccioppoli theorem or provide a reference for it? A simple google search doesn't seem to give anything.

Comment: @MohithRaju I think it is actually known as the "Hadamard-Caccioppoli" theorem, you should be able to find references under that name.

Comment: The affirmation is false for $n=1$. Take for instance the sine function with $U=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @BlueNight but sine is not locally injective at every point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way to find such an example is to take any non-constant holomorphic function $f:U \to \mathbb{C}$ and throw away the points where $f' = 0$. A holomorphic function is locally injective if $f'(z) \neq 0$, so we need only ensure that the function is not globally injective.

As I pointed out in a comment, we can take $U = \mathbb{C} \smallsetminus \{0\}$ and $f(z) = z^n$ for $n \geq 2$. Or, if you prefer, $f(z) = e^z$ on all of $\mathbb{C}$ for the most simple-minded examples.

These examples are easily extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n \geq 2$, simply by writing $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-2} \ni(z,v)$ and considering $g(z,v) = (f(z), v)$. I'll leave it to your creativity to build many more and more interesting examples.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the continously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with
\begin{align*}
f(x,y):=\begin{pmatrix}e^x\cos(y)\\e^x\sin(y)\end{pmatrix}\text{ and } Df(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}e^x\cos(y)&-e^x\sin(y)\\e^x\sin(y)&e^x\cos(y)\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
We see that $\det(Df(x,y))\neq0$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, so we can apply the inverse function theorem to all points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Hence, $f$ is locally injective everywhere. As $f(0,\pi)=f(0,3\pi)$ it's clear that $f$ can't be (globally) injective.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the set $\{(x,y)|1\lt x\lt2 \& 0\lt y\lt7\}$ and $f$ be $(x,y) \mapsto (x\times\sin(y), x\times\cos(y))$ . $f$ is locally injective on $U$ but $f(1,0)=f(1,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let *U* ⊂ **R**, and let  **f**: *U* ⊂ **R $\to R^2$**  be  **t** $\to$ **($t^2$ - 1 , t($t^2$ - 1))**. It is locally injective at all points of **R**, but not injective in any interval **(-a,a)** with **$a\gt 1$**, because **f(-1)=f(1)=(0,0)**